John and I [have planned]/[are planning]/[plan] to go
Suppose John and Sarah are going to go to the beach today. They don't want to go alone, so they're calling their friends and asking them if they would like to join them. So they call Bob, he picks up, and Sarah says to him:
Hi Bob, John and I [have planned]/[are planning]/[plan] to go to the beach today. Do you want to come with us?
Can all three options be used in this case, and do they all convey the idea that going to the beach is a current plan? Thanks.

All are fine. In other contexts the have planned would convey that their planning had been completed, as in We have planned it all out, so all that remains is to execute the plan successfully.
But here there’s really no difference in meaning among the three.
(See also this very similar question.)
